# I can't see my texture on maya

Tags: object, textures, maya

I have UV mapped the object, And added a texture material, But i can't see the texture.

Error image

[image: [Image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press the hotkey 6 ( or 5), it will activate the "Show Texture Mode" in Maya. This will enable the textures in the view port.